# Creating Google Cloud Function via Java API: "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a Google Cloud Function using the Java Client API with this client:

```
Credentials myCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(keyFile));
CloudFunctionsServiceSettings settings = CloudFunctionsServiceSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(myCredentials)).build();
client = CloudFunctionsServiceClient.create(settings);


String project = "my-project-name";
String location = "us-central1";

LocationName locationName = LocationName.of( project, location );
CloudFunction function = CloudFunction.newBuilder().build();
CloudFunction response = client.createFunctionAsync(locationName, function).get();
```

I tried different invocations but I'am getting always the following stack trace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request has errors
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:566)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:547)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:86)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
        at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.get(OperationFutureImpl.java:127)
        at it.myapp.test.App.main(App.java:59)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request has errors
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
        at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1041)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1215)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:464)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:428)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:461)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:553)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:68)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:739)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:718)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request has errors
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
        ... 16 more
```

My pom.xml have the following setup:

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-functions-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-functions</artifactId>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does anyone know what do i wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Include on your post how you declared `project` and `location` and please don't post your project ID in clear text.

Comment: String project = "my-project-name";
String location = "us-central1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your Function Builder is missing the required parameters in order to create the function. If you try to create a function via Cloud Console, you're required to enter details such as function name, entrypoint, runtime, trigger type, and source code.

I've already reached out to the engineers and they are now informed with regards to the lack of details in the log output.

As a solution, here's a sample code that will create a Cloud Function running on Java 11. Of course you can always choose any type of runtime you want:

```
package function;

import com.google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.functions.v1.HttpsTrigger;
import com.google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.v1.LocationName;

public class App {
  public static void main( String[] args ){
    try {

      // TODO: Add your credentials here

      CloudFunctionsServiceClient cloudFunctionsServiceClient = CloudFunctionsServiceClient.create();
      String location = LocationName.of("[PROJECT_ID]", "us-central1").toString();
      CloudFunction function = CloudFunction.newBuilder()
        .setName(location + "/functions/[FUNCTION_NAME]")
        .setEntryPoint("functions.HelloHttp") // fully qualified class name (FQN)
        .setRuntime("java11")
        .setHttpsTrigger(HttpsTrigger.getDefaultInstance())
        .setSourceArchiveUrl("gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/source_code.zip")
        .build(); 
  
      CloudFunction response = cloudFunctionsServiceClient.createFunctionAsync(location, function).get();
    }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: If your zipped source code is from a storage bucket, make sure your source files **are at the root of the ZIP file**, rather than a folder containing the files.